# How to get the sum of data from a table without making multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently running this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(name) AS ActionCount 
FROM plays 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY ActionCount DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

To select the most prominent/common names in a game of mine, how would I also get the total sum of the mileage every player drove through without running a query for every one of the 50 users selected above assuming I have a 'mileage' field in every game.

Comment: Seems like your table schema would be useful.

Comment: only mileage and name are relevant from the plays table

Comment: have you tried using `SUM(mileage)`?

Comment: You'll find that you get answers faster if you try Googling a couple keywords in your question, like [sum mysql](https://www.google.com/search?q=sum%20mysql) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have expected that:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  COUNT(name) AS ActionCount,
  SUM(mileage) AS totalMileage 
FROM plays 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY ActionCount DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Would do it.

It doesn't seem particularly tricky to me?

Comment: and order by actioncount? :-)

Comment: There is no actioncount, that was for the other query!

Comment: aha sorry I didn't relate the "counter-name"-field to the alias actioncount.

Comment: What counter-name field? Are you on the same planet as the rest of us?

Comment: This would require to run an additional 50 queries to get the info is that correct?

Comment: @user2213400 How do you mean?

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic - I meant COUNT(name) AS ActionCount as stated in original question

Comment: I was confused by your comment that said: "only mileage and name are relevant from the plays table". That is obviously rubbish. If you had the slightest competence you would simply combine the query I showed with what you have. Since you do not appear to be capable of this, I will do it for you.

Comment: It isn't rubbish because that's the only data you need access too. Thanks for the answer, didn't need to be a bitch about it, some people (like myself) didn't know you can combine statements like that.